# Bootstrap installed in CI3 but can't run

Tags: css, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I installed bootstrap in ci3 but its not working

It says 200 ok but the bootstrap isnt working

Ive tried to see the base url and it could link to the css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HJu0.png)

Comment: can you please give some example hows bootstrap is not working in yourproject?

Comment: Hint:use CDN for bootstrap-4